# How to monitor online status of app users in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, sql, xamarin.forms

I've been creating small offline apps for Android for a few months now and have always been curious about creating an app that shows a list of online/offline users. I also began coding in Xamarin, specifically Xamarin.Forms for cross-platform development. I have some database experience and have created a small schema to store basic user information. What I'd like to figure out is how to create an app that does just two things:

- Allows users to log in (let's say the database already contains their info).
- Displays the status (either Online or Offline if they're logged in or not) of other users who exist in the database.

I've only used databases for creating web pages in JSP, so I' not sure of what packages/APIs are used to connect to (and which) servers are used for Xamarin.Forms apps.

EDIT: My thinking is that the app would have to constantly be checking the database and seeing if a boolean variable is either true or false (online or offline) which is where I was confused as to how a server could handle hundreds/thousands of users constantly bombarding it with requests for online/offline status of every user.

Comment: take a look at Xamarin Insights: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/insights/

Answer (score 1):

If you want do this yourself, you have to create a webservice, that access a (central) database and then implement your own methods to reach your target. 
In my app, I have implemented various functions for that. E.G.:
- Log function by start of the app:
  - Query some data form the device, send it to the web-service, store it on a sql-server (so that we can see which users on which OS and which devices) have loaded the app at which datetime 
- user-verification:
  - check if the user-nickname and password is valid (found on the sql-server)
we have implemented a JSON webservice for that. 
Or you use - like Sten Petrov mentioned - insights. 
If you add insights to your project, it does a lot for you.
As the implementation over an own webservice is not uncomplex (especially if you don't have already one in place), I suggest you to have a look at insights.